# Maven or Tomcat overriding my Java class properties

Tags: java, class, tomcat

So I have a "Server" class with some properties, one of them being "joinSession" that is a boolean, false by default.

I have a setter and getter for that and it works perfectly fine. However my problem is, when more than 1 person connects to my application (which sometimes causes the setter function to turn "joinSession" to true) they same to share the value of joinSession... so if client2 changes it to true, then client1 who should still have the default false value, actually turns true as well...

If this doesn't make sense and you need to see code, please let me know. Thanks

CODE: (A lot of uncontributing code has been removed due to NDA)

```
public class TunnelServlet {

    Server server = new Server("MY_PATH", "MY_JWT");
    if (request.getParameter("joinSession").equals("true") {
        server.setJoinSession(true);
    }

    System.out.println(server.getJoinSession);
}
```

And my Server class

```
public class Server {
    private static String path;
    private static String JWToken;
    private static boolean joinSession;

    Server( String domain, String token ) {
        path = "http://" + domain + ":8000/" ;
        JWToken = token;
    }

    public void setJoinSession(boolean isJoinSession) {
        joinSession = isJoinSession;
    }

    public boolean getJoinSession() {
        return joinSession;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need the code and what is the question?

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan Trying to stop the overriding of the value of "joinSession" when another users changes it...  and I'll edit code in a minute with code

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan For example: Client1 connects and gets default value of 'joinSession = false'.... if no one else connects it stays like this... now lets assume Client2 connects, and calls action that will change his 'joinSession' into true... now for some reason, Client1 also has joinSession = false, how to stop this?

Comment: Can you share the code please? I think your `joinSession` is a static field so that it belongs to your server class and everyone is changing it. So you need to avoid this, but I need to see the code please

Comment: @MadoBaker  Unless you [edit] your question and include the code, your post is off-topic.  Nobody can possibly help you without seeing the code.  It sounds like you need to implement the concept of a client "session".  The Servlet spec already has a mechanism for this.  Maven is a build tool and has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan it indeed is static, is that the problem? and I added code

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan THANK YOU SO MUCH, you have no idea the headaches this has caused me for the PAST WEEK. You are a god given gift. I love you.

Comment: Then if it is ok I'll answer to your question and could you please accept and upvote my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `joinSession` is a static field so that it belongs to your server class and everyone is changing it. You should not do this because static fields belongs to class not to objects. If this field is required for everyone you should not make it static. This will solve your problem.